# add a base url or context root for a node js application

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am writing a python script for auto deployment of node js application which will run behind nginx proxy server.How is it possible to mention a base url for a particular app. Like suppose I am deploying a health application and suppose the url is http://localhost:9000/. So I want to run it using http://localhost:9000/health/ . I know that is possible if i mention it inside application explicitly. But is there anyway to mention it via command prompt or in package.json file.

Please help

Comment: can i mention it inside package.json ? or any effective way of doing so...

Comment: which method so u use

Comment: the base url will work as a prefix to every request. Like suppose:  /health/getuserdetails  /health/deleteuser/:id

Comment: so you need to use get method..

Comment: does someone know the answer....then plzz help